# Multiprocessing with Return values

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a problem will multiprocessing to speed up some processing of files which are stored on S3 which need to be checked. Since I am now new to using multiprocessing I am not sure what exactly is wrong the code was running without issued when I had it with just a for-loop.

```
def read_json(file):
  file_key = file["Key"]
  file_key_split = file_key.split("/")
  document = get_json_details(file_key)
  type = file_key_split[2]  
return document, type

document_list = []
document_type_list = []

mgr = mp.Manager()
nodes = mgr.list()
pool_size = mp.cpu_count()
pool = mp.Pool(processes=pool_size)
# mp.freeze_support()

for file in tqdm(get_all_s3_objects(s3, Bucket=docbucket, Prefix=prefix)):
    document_list, document_type_list = zip(*pool.map(read_json, file))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The error I get is the following:

````
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tobia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\tobia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "c:\GIT\BMWJPSI-BI\03_Lambda_Functions\RegoOCRCheck.py", line 118, in read_json
    file_key = file["Key"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/GIT/BMWJPSI-BI/03_Lambda_Functions/RegoOCRCheck.py", line 151, in <module>
    document_list, document_type_list = zip(pool.map(read_json, file))
  File "C:\Users\tobia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\tobia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: string indices must be integers```

Thanks for your help.
````

Comment: It seems like the parameter `file` passed in is a string type value so it's displaying the error above and that previously it is a dictionary object when just running inside a for loop, Could you post the original code that was working? That way it might be easier for us to debug

Comment: @user696969 File is a dictionary and has not changed. The problem I think is related that one of the return values is a list and the other one a string. The running code is the following:

```    for file in tqdm(get_all_s3_objects(s3, Bucket=docbucket, Prefix=prefix)):
        dl, dtl = read_json(file)
        document_list.append(dl)
        document_type_list.append(dtl)
```
sample return in my case for one iteration is document = ["blabla", "hello world"] type = "picture"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed response, I think the issue you're having is that you're passing a dictionary object into the `pool.map` function, which will only iterating through the keys of the dictionary instead of passing the dictionary object itself. I think instead of iterating through each individual `file` and run the `pool.map`, you should try passing the entire `get_all_s3_objects(s3, Bucket=docbucket, Prefix=prefix)` into the `pool.map` function which will be iterated and return as list of tuples where each tuple is `(document_list, document_type_list)`

```
document_list, document_type_list = zip(*pool.map(read_json, get_all_s3_objects(s3, Bucket=docbucket, Prefix=prefix)))
```

Let me know if you're still encountering any issues

Comment: I have to remove the tqdm() part than it works! Thanks for the hint. 
that part works 
```document_list, document_type_list = zip(
        *pool.map(read_json, get_all_s3_objects(s3, Bucket=docbucket, Prefix=prefix))
    )```

Can you correct it in your answer that I can mark it as successful. I was not able to edit it.